How to handle Wordpress/WooCommerce notice display logic?
So WooCommerce has various functions to handle notices pretty easily within any front-end hooks, similarly, Wordpress has various functions to handle notices pretty easily within any back-end hooks. Due to both WooCommerce and Wordpress needing to be used to display notices for both sides of a plugin I'm working on, I decided to try to make a class for handling both front-end and back-end notices more easily. This was easy until I got to handling both front-end and back-end AJAX functions. AJAX functions seem to require an additional step on the JS side to actually display any notices created within the AJAX function.
Here's the code below to get a front-end notice to appear:
jQuery/AJAX
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'notice_function',
        },
        success: function(response) { 
            $('woocommerce-notices-wrapper').append(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});

PHP Callback:
function notice_function() {
    wc_add_notice("Success!", "notice");
    wc_print_notices();
        
    wp_die();
}

To display a front-end notice you seemingly must use the line  $('woocommerce-notices-wrapper').append(response) to get the notice to display. I do know I could just make a function within JS that does this whenever I need it, but I was looking to try to keep all of the notice logic within the notice object I'm creating so that I can just create a notice object within any type of hook and be able to see the notice in "real-time" (without refreshing the page). If I were to create a function in JS to handle this I would also have to load the file that includes the function everywhere so that I can access it anywhere.
Basically, I'm now wondering if there's a better approach to this problem or if it's impossible to trigger the notice to display from within the object/PHP itself.
